# gtk: how to change the angle of a GtkLabel in CSS

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I want to change the angle of a GtkLabel in CSS from `.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.

What the name of the CSS property to change?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the angle of the text from CSS: the [GtkLabel:angle property](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkLabel.html#GtkLabel--angle) is only accessible programmatically, and not part of the style mechanism.